# error 'info' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

Having trouble with structures. How do i declare this? I need to d the following:

Your function will return an integer.

- Your function should only accept one argument (an array).
- Your function will ask the user for the number of characters that will be inputted. Then, inside your
  function, you will check if this value is greater than or equal to 70. If the values is greater than or equal to
  70, you will print out an error message and return 1. Otherwise, you will use a loop to scan the characters
  and return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info {
    char name[70];
    char lastname[70];
    char address[70];
};

void printarray(char name[]) {
    int i;
    int number;
    printf("How many characters will be inputted? \n");
    printf("It cannot be more than 70!\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("What is your name? \n");
    for(i=0; i<number; i++) {
        scanf(" %c", &info.name[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    struct info name;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please properly format code samples inside code blocks so that others can read your code easily to better assist you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You never call to printarray function in main

Comment: info is the name of a type like int or float.  scanf needs a variable name to put the stuff into and not the type of the variable - you wouldn't write `scanf(" %d", &int);` for the same reason  The way to fix it is to  make a variable of `struct info` type and then use that in the scanf call.  You could even call it info (but I wouldn't - imagine the confusion that would create!)

Comment: Why are you calling `scanf (" %c",...)` in a loop to collect characters in the first place?  Why not call `scanf (" %70s",...)` instead and then the user doesn't need to say how many characters they are going to put in.

Comment: In `printarray`, where you have `&info.name[i]`, what are you expecting `info` to be referring to? And why?

Comment: Also, if parameter you are going to pass in to printarray is a string then scanf should take a string.  In that case your `scanf (" %c",...)` line should be `scanf (" %c",&name[i])` and then you call printarray from main like `printarray(name.name);`

Comment: Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/SJTL2Ze1D

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `info` is not the name of a type. `struct info` is the name of a type.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, regarding: `scanf (" %70s",...)`  The input format conversion specifier: `%s` always appends a `NUL` byte to the input, so the 'length' modifier has to be 1 less than than the length of the input buffer.   Always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( scanf( "%69s:, ... ) != 1 ) { //handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
struct info {
    char name[70];
    char lastname[70];
    char address[70];
};
```

defines a structure template, not a structure variable, so you can't use `scanf(" %c", &info.name[i]);` becuase `struct info` is a data type defined by you.

Inside `main()` you defined the structure variable `name`.

As you said in your question, that when the `number` is `>= 70`, it should print an error msg and `return 1;` but you aren't checking for the error.

Lastly, you never called `printarray()`.

Probably, you want to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info {
    char name[70];
    char lastname[70];
    char address[70];
};

void printarray(struct info var) {
    int i;
    int number;
    printf("How many characters will be inputted? \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number >= 70)
    {
      printf("Number should be less than 70.\n");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("What is your name? \n");
    for(i=0; i<number; i++) {
        scanf(" %c", &var.name[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    struct info name;
    printarray(name);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The code has several defects:**

1. The program is supposed to receive a char array, not a struct template.
2. No condition is set to compare the number with `>= 70`.
3. The function `printarray(char[])` was never used.
4. The function `printarray()` returns nothing (i.e. void), expecting to return an integer `1` or `0` is impossible with it.
5. `return` in the last line of the function, isn't required.
6. The identifier `info` in the syntax:

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &info.name[i]); // obviously an error
   ```

   is a type name and not an instance of `info` struct.

**Aside:** Avoid using magical numbers, use constants when the number isn't going to be changed anywhere (e.g. `MAX` which holds `70` integer value in the program given).

---

**Example code redefined is as follows:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 70

// struct template
struct info {
    char name[MAX];
    // ...
};

// function declaration
int print_array(info);

int main(void) {
    info in;
    int exit_code;

    // passing a single argument
    exit_code = print_array(in);

    printf("\nExit code was: %d\n", exit_code);

    return 0;
}

// function definition
int print_array(info i) {
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number (not >= 70): ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num >= 70) {
        printf("The input exceeds the limit.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int it = 0; it < num; it++)
        i.name[it] = getchar();
        
    printf("%s\n", i.name);
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

---

**The code will output:**

```
Enter a number (not >= 70): 30
Hello world, how are you today? hope you're doing good!

Hello world, how are you toda    // rest are truncated

Exit code was: 0
```